# ParseFromString failure to decode message

Tags: python, rest, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to interface with a RESTful API that accepts application/x-protobuf objects in post.

.proto example object:

```
message register
{
    required string name = 1;
    required int32 id = 2;
}
```

using requests I'm able to POST this message to the server and receive a 200.

e.g.

```
register = protobuf_pb2.register()
register.name = "foo"
register.id = 1

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=register.SerializeToString(), headers=headers)
```

when I look at this payload in SerializeToString() format it shows similar to

> b'\n\t\n\x03foo\x10\x01'

As a sanity check, I can then create a new message object and .ParseFromString() on that back into the correct message format.

A second uri on the server allows you to send a GET request to retrieve that same data. So I used the following:

```
register = protobuf_pb2.register()
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers).content
register.ParseFromString(response)
```

The response returns

> b'foo:1\n'

And ParseFromString returns the exception

> DecodeError('Error parsing message',)

Am I missing a step somewhere? 
Should the .content payload be encoded somehow before being parsed?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object you are getting back from the server is binary data, UTF-8 encoded, so Python interprets it as a `bytes` object (in Python 3, `bytes` and `str` are different types).

```
m = b'foo:1\n'
type(m)
Out[1]: bytes

m.decode('utf-8')
Out[2]: 'foo:1\n'
```

`ParseFromString` however expects a string, so it throws a `DecodeError`; just use the `decode()` with the appropriate encoding.

In the response headers you should be able to find the encoding used: pretty much everyone uses UTF-8, but in "real" Production code, you should check that too: in the `Content-Type` (or you can even request a specific one with `Accept-Charset` but you may get a 406, if the server cannot fulfil it).